# What Jewish leaders/rabbis/prophets were active in years 3350-3360?

Tags: history, rabbis, navi-prophets

What Jewish leaders/rabbis/prophets were active in years 3350-3360 (in Jewish calendar years)? and died around 3360...

Comment: Hey Jon, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Adding some context to your question, such as why you're interested in rabbis from this (very) specific period of history or what region of the world you're interested in, might help in answering the question.

Comment: Also, there's some confusion in the answers as to whether you mean 3350 BCE, or 3350 Jewish calendar years.....you may want to [clarify that](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/posts/45340/edit)

Comment: I needed a rough list of Jewish leaders during that time peirod for a bit of research... I'm trying to piece together a timeline of a very specific story for a personal project. And as you said below, if the years are going up... it generally means that it is not BCE, and well... history is history, and year 3350 hasn't exactly happened yet in the Xian calendar... That would leave us with the only other useful calendar being the Jewish one... I assumed that it would be assumed... and there weren't any rabbis at 3350 BCE...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming we use the conventional Jewish chronology, that puts us right during the Babylonian exile. 2414 years ago = 400 BCE; conventional chronology has the first Temple destroyed 20 years earlier and rebuilt 50 years later. (The secular sources have a missing century or so, which would put this instead in early Second Temple years, but that's for another time.)

Key Biblical figures of the exile period are: Jeremiah (witnesses the first Temple's destruction), Ezekiel (had been exiled off to Babylon a few years before the destruction); Daniel, Chananya, Mishael, and Azarya -- all brought off to Babylon as children; and Mordechai of the Purim story. Not to mention the exiled King Zedekiah, who dies in Babylonian captivity -- if you're looking for someone who dies 20 years into the exile, that's probably pretty close.

Comment: Also Jehoiachin, who was exiled before Zedekiah

Comment: @Shalom Thank you! I was trying to situate my self properly for some research... and I'm no the best with history.